# How to change the 'tag' when logging to syslog from 'Unknown'?

Tags: python, django, osx-lion

I'm logging to syslog fine but can't work out how to specify the 'tag'. The logging currently posts this:

```
Mar  3 11:45:34 TheMacMini Unknown: INFO FooBar
```

but I want that 'Unknown' to be set to something. eg:

```
Mar  3 11:45:34 TheMacMini Foopybar: INFO FooBar
```

If I use `logger` from the command line it can be controlled via the `-t` option...

```
$ logger -t Foopybar FooBar && tail -1 /var/log/system.log
Mar  3 12:05:00 TheMacMini Foopybar[4566]: FooBar
```

But logging from python I don't seem to be able to specify the tag:

```
import logging
logging.info("FooBar")
```

Just gives me the 'Unknown' tag shown at the top. I've defined this spec:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'syslog':{
            'address': '/var/run/syslog',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            'facility': 'local2',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['syslog'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            }
    }
}
```

How do I specify the tag so it's not always "Unknown"?

Answer (score 17):

## Simple Way of Tagging Log Messages

Do this:
`logging.info("TagName: FooBar")`
and you message will be tagged! You just need to start  all your messages with "TagName: ". And this is of course not very elegant.

## Better Solution

Setup your logger:

```
log = logging.getLogger('name')
address=('log-server',logging.handlers.SYSLOG_UDP_PORT)
facility=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_USER
h=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler( address,facility )
f = logging.Formatter('TagName: %(message)s')
h.setFormatter(f)
log.addHandler(h)
```

And use it:

```
log.info('FooBar')
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm adding this just for the sake of completion, even though @sasha's answer is absolutely correct.

If you happen to log messages to syslog directly using `syslog.syslog`, you can set the tag using the `syslog.openlog` function:

```
import syslog
syslog.openlog('foo')
syslog.syslog('bar')
```

Going back to the linux shell:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Sep  7 07:01:58 dev-balthazar foo: bar
```

Comment: You need to remember to call syslog.closelog() when you are done.